# Unable to install python3-pip on Debian 8

Tags: debian, python, dependencies, python3

I want to install python3-pip but I always get errors:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3-pip : Depends: python3-setuptools but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

---

```
sudo apt-get install python-setuptools


The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3-setuptools : Depends: python3-pkg-resources (= 5.5.1-1) but 33.1.1-1~bpo8+1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

---

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pkg-resources


Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
python3-pkg-resources is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
```

---

I already did update/upgrade but it still does not work

Answer (score 1):

The `python3-pkg-resources` is removed from jessie-backports.

```
sudo apt purge python3-pkg-resources
```

It will be installed from the `main` repository as dependencies.

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

Comment: Thanks this worked for me

Answer (score 0):

You could try

- `sudo apt-get install python3-pkg-resources`
- `sudo apt-get install -f python3-pip`

Maybe this is the solution, but I'm really not sure.

Comment: Unfortunately this also does not work: Still broken packages

Answer (score 0):

For those who are still stuck on reinstalling Python3 after doing some unholy (to Debian) removal of Python3 (and not using the apt-get remove python3 correctly, I offer this 100% recovery step.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58980420/4379130